# Change JList item colour when I want

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlist

I'm trying to build a `JList` in which some of the items have a different background colour than others but only when I want it.

I've been trying to do something like this up it produces errors.

```
 static DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();

 for(int K=0;K<Collectionsize();K++){
        Jlist.setForeground(Color.red); 
        model.addElement(type 1);

        for(int I=0;I<(subcollection.size();I++){
            Jlist.setForeground(Color.white); 
            model.addElement(type 2);
            }
        }
```

There is no pattern between type 1 and 2 so I want change the colour when I want it rather than rely on if statements.

I see a lot of people talking about building custom render classes but I was aiming some something more simple.

Comment: *"I see a lot of people talking about building custom render classes but I was aiming some something more simple."* You are mistaken in thinking a different approach will be simpler.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP wants the simplest approach but has already rejected it!

Comment: (1-) `I see a lot of people...` - so why would a lot of people use a complicated solution if an easier solution existed? Don't you think a lot of people would use the easier and commonly accepted approach?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I see a lot of customer render classes but all of them seem to be focused around "if it contains character Y colour it blue", what I'm looking for is a simple action which lets me change the colour only for when I want it. If I have to use a custom render class I'll use it but I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: You have to use a custom cell renderer.  There is no avoiding it.

Comment: @VGR Well off to write a lot of code to turn a list cell a slightly different colour

Comment: *"when I want it"* and when you want it to happen? For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve] and also follow the above recommendations, i.e. use a render class, there's no other way

Comment: @Frakcool basically I have a collection of albums and tracks, every time the title of an album is printed to the list I want a different colour from each time a track name is printed to the list. I can't provide an complete example of this section because its across multiple classes and kind of complex.

Comment: *"I can't provide an complete example of this section because its across multiple classes"* An MCVE **can** contain multiple classes. *"..and kind of complex"* Simplify it! Remove the irrelevant cruft for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: A list of items containing two pieces of information per item is better suited to being displayed in a table rather than a list, though you might adapt this to a list if needed. The same basic principle applies (use a rendering component).

This is what I mean:

[image]

Which is achieved by this rendering class:

```
class TrackCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    HashMap<String, Color> colorMap = new HashMap<>();
    Random r = new Random();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        JLabel l = (JLabel) c;

        String s = (String) value;
        if (column == 0) {
            if (!colorMap.containsKey(s)) {
                Color clr = new Color(
                        150 + r.nextInt(105),
                        150 + r.nextInt(105),
                        150 + r.nextInt(105));
                colorMap.put(s, clr);
            }
            Color color = colorMap.get(s);
            l.setBackground(color);
            l.setOpaque(true);
        } else {
            l.setOpaque(false);
        }

        return l;
    }
}
```

Note: it might be best to use an enum rather than randomly assigning a color, but with 3 albums and over a million possible colors, we should be pretty safe.

In this (two class) MCVE of just over 100 lines of code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AlbumTrackTable {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String[][] playList = {
        {"The Will to Live", "Faded"},
        {"The Will to Live", "Homeless Child"},
        {"Oh Mercy", "Political Wrold"},
        {"Oh Mercy", "What Was it You Wanted?"},
        {"Red Sails in the Sunset", "Helps Me Helps You"},
        {"Red Sails in the Sunset", "Redneck Wonderland"}
    };
    String[] columnNames = {"Album", "Track"};

    AlbumTrackTable() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        DefaultTableModel trackModel = new DefaultTableModel(playList, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(trackModel);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        TableCellRenderer renderer = new TrackCellRenderer();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                AlbumTrackTable o = new AlbumTrackTable();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class TrackCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    HashMap<String, Color> colorMap = new HashMap<>();
    Random r = new Random();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        JLabel l = (JLabel) c;

        String s = (String) value;
        if (column == 0) {
            if (!colorMap.containsKey(s)) {
                Color clr = new Color(
                        150 + r.nextInt(105),
                        150 + r.nextInt(105),
                        150 + r.nextInt(105));
                colorMap.put(s, clr);
            }
            Color color = colorMap.get(s);
            l.setBackground(color);
            l.setOpaque(true);
        } else {
            l.setOpaque(false);
        }

        return l;
    }
}
```